Complexity of Scheduling n Tasks on m Machines with Identical Execution Times, Dependencies, and Time Lags
This is a scheduling problem with $n$ tasks across $m$ machines. Tasks have dependencies (DAG) and can be divided into two types: A) need resources $R$ and have an identical execution time. B) do not need resources $R$ and have varying execution times. The number of machines $m$ is always sufficient during the scheduling, so the bottleneck is only about the limited resource $R$.
Resources $R$ are renewable, and the capacity available in every period is $k$.
The goal is to determine the minimum makespan (i.e., the total time to complete all tasks)
First I searched for Resource-Constrained Project Scheduling Problem and found it has been proved NP-hard by reducing to 3-partition problem. However in that case machine is limited.
Then, I try to change the problem this way: a scheduling problem with $n\prime$ tasks across $k$ machines. $n\prime$ is the number of tasks that need resources $R$. Each task has an identical execution time. There are dependencies between tasks that a DAG can represent, and tasks have time lags that must be respected. If task $t_2$ depends on task $t_1$, and the time lags $l_{ij}$ between task $t_1$ and task $t_2$, thus the start time of $t_2$ $>=$ end time of $t_1$ + $l_{ij}$.
What is the computational complexity of this scheduling problem? I understand that without considering time lags, this problem is NP-hard. I am unsure how the introduction of time lags affects the complexity. Since there are non-zero time lags, I can't directly conclude that the problem is NP-hard just because it's NP-hard in the special case where all time lags are zero.
Could you recommend resources, papers, or textbooks that delve into similar problems?
Thank you in advance for your help!

What's the relationship between a time lag and an execution time?  Do you mean that if task $t_1$ has completed execution and task $t_2$ depends on task $t_1$ we still might not be able to start $t_2$ due to the lag time?  If the lag time is less than the execution time, does it mean $t_2$ can start before $t_1$ has completed execution?  Can you [edit] the post to more explicitly define what are the conditions for a candidate schedule to be valid?

Isn't it trivial that with time lags it will also be NP-hard (consider the special case where the time lag = the execution time)?  What am I missing?

Thank you, I've found a trivial reduction between the two problems. The case without time lags doesn't mean that all time lags are zero, but rather that all time lags are equal. For my problem, I can construct some special cases where all the time lags are equal.

Perhaps you can write an answer to your own question, to try to be helpful to others in the future?

When considering scheduling with time lags, one special case is when all the time lags are the same. In this scenario, the problem is equivalent to scheduling, where the execution time of each task becomes the original execution time of the task plus the time lag. This has been proven to be NP in the paper NP-Complete Scheduling Problems
